# nested classes in GDB

Tags: c++, casting, gdb, nested-class

In my C++ program I have a nested class defined as follows:

```
class A {

  class B {
    // ...
  }

  // ...
}
```

When I try casting a pointer in GDB like this: `set $b = (A::B*)p`
I get "A syntax error in expression"

I'm not familiar with the symbol (or debugging) information stored in the ELF files. I'm wondering what's wrong with my casting here and how to refer to a nested class in GDB.

Comment: What version of `gdb`  are you using? On which system (Linux?)? IIRC, it did significant progress on these matters recently. Installing a newer version of `gdb` might be worthwhile!

Comment: Thanks Basile. I tried the latest GDB (7.3.1) but it gave me the same error: "(gdb) set $b = (A::B*)0x1
A syntax error in expression, near `)0x1'."

Comment: My Linux distribution is "Fedora release 13 (Goddard)" and the kernel is "2.6.34.9-69.fc13.x86_64 #1 SMP"

Answer (score 2):

The answer is to enclose the class name in single quotes:

```
set $b = ('A::B'*)p
```

See http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=8693

Answer (score 1):

Works for me (using current CVS GDB, as well as 7.3.1):

```
$ cat t.cc
struct A {
  struct B {
    int x;
  };
  int y;
};

int main()
{
  A::B ab, *p = &ab;
  return 0;
}

$ gcc -g t.cc && gdb -q ./a.out
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4005b8: file t.cc, line 10.
(gdb) r

Breakpoint 1, main () at t.cc:10
10    A::B ab, *p = &ab;
(gdb) p (A::B*)0x1
$1 = (A::B *) 0x1
(gdb) set $a =  (A::B*)0x1
(gdb) p $a
$2 = (A::B *) 0x1
(gdb) quit
```

Comment: Thanks! You are right. It works for latest 7.4.50 (but not for 7.3.1 from the GNU FTP). Looks like a bug in GDB. Thanks again!